# Run MSsql Query something like foreach

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, one is called Product and another one is called ProductVariant. ProductVariant has ID from Product. I need to do simple operation on both tables.

Here is the query that I come up with:

```
declare @id int

declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select @id = ProductID  from Product WHERE (Published = '0')

open cur

fetch next from cur into @id 

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

UPDATE Productvariant SET Cost = SalePrice WHERE VariantID = @id;
UPDATE ProductVariant SET SalePrice = 0.00 WHERE VariantID = @id; 

fetch next from cur into @id 
END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

But it gives me:
 Msg 154, Level 15, State 3, Line 4
variable assignment is not allowed in a cursor declaration.

Thanks

Comment: just remove the @id from the select - you are already fetching that value with `fetch next....` line

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. However running the cursor did change the values correctly, but something happened to the DB and it become extremely slow. I did the test three times in a row on 2 diferent servers with same thing. It is slow after... what happened to the DB?!??

Comment: To add... I have not tried other queries from other people. I will try them ASAP and see if I get more slowdowns.

Comment: You should avoid using cursors ... slows things down. use set-based alternatives whenever you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e2e5/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Product
(
  ProductID int,
  Published char(1)
);

create table ProductVariant
(
  VariantID int,
  Cost money,
  SalePrice money
);

insert into Product values
(1, '0'),
(2, '1'),
(3, '0')

insert into ProductVariant values
(1, 0, 10),
(1, 0, 11),
(2, 0, 20),
(2, 0, 21),
(3, 0, 30),
(3, 0, 31);
```

**Query 1**:

```
UPDATE ProductVariant 
SET    Cost = SalePrice, 
       SalePrice = 0.00 
FROM   Product 
WHERE  Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.VariantID AND
       Product.Published = '0';

SELECT *
FROM ProductVariant;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e2e5/3/0)**:

```
| VARIANTID | COST | SALEPRICE |
--------------------------------
|         1 |   10 |         0 |
|         1 |   11 |         0 |
|         2 |    0 |        20 |
|         2 |    0 |        21 |
|         3 |   30 |         0 |
|         3 |   31 |         0 |
```

Comment: How do I run that code on every row? Right now it runs only for one row. I am sorry for my mssql ignorance. Thanks

Comment: @VedranWexMaricevic You don't have to do anything. This will update all rows in `ProductVariant` that is referencing a row in `Product` where `Published` is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like :

```
UPDATE ProductVariant SET Cost =SalePrice , SalePrice = 0.00
WHERE VariantID IN (SELECT productID FROM Product WHERE Published = '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 lines should be:

```
declare @id int

declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select ProductID  from Product WHERE (Published = '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning how to use cursor, just remove the @id from the select - you are already fetching that value with fetch next.... line.

```
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select ProductID  from Product WHERE (Published = '0')
```

But another alternative better than cursor should be used

```
declare @id int
declare @idTable as table(id int)

insert into @idTable
select ProductID  from Product WHERE (Published = '0')

while(exists(select top(1) id from @idTable)) 
begin
    select top(1) @id = id from @idTable

    UPDATE Productvariant SET Cost = SalePrice WHERE VariantID = @id;
    UPDATE ProductVariant SET SalePrice = 0.00 WHERE VariantID = @id; 

    delete top(1) from @idTable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select ProductID  from Product WHERE (Published = '0')
```

You don't need the `select @id = ProductID` because that's what the fetch does for you. It fetches the value of `ProductID`  and puts it into `@id`

Hope that helps